# Jest Unit Test keeps failing: Test suite failed to run, Unexpected token (8:19)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I recently wanted to learn how to write tests for ReactJS.
Using [this](https://github.com/vjwilson/enzyme-example-jest/tree/master/src) example and the various configurations on airbnb and facebook/jest, I tried my luck.

```
//.babelrc
{
  "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }], "react"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
       "presets": [["es2015"], "react"]
     }
   }
}
```

This my Foo.js file, from the mentioned example:

```
//Foo.js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
const propTypes = {};
const defaultProps = {};

class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='foo'>
        Bar
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Foo.propTypes = propTypes;
Foo.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Foo;
```

This is my test file, also from the example:

```
//Foo.test.js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';

import Foo from './Foo';

describe('A suite', () => {
  it('should render without throwing an error', () => {
    expect(shallow(<Foo />).contains(<div className='foo'>Bar</div>)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should be selectable by class "foo"', () => {
    expect(shallow(<Foo />).is('.foo')).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should mount in a full DOM', () => {
    expect(mount(<Foo />).find('.foo').length).toBe(1);
  });

  it('should render to static HTML', () => {
    expect(render(<Foo />).text()).toEqual('Bar');
  });
});
```

I don't know what I am missing. I have looked through many GitHub Issues, and SO Questions and Answers, but I can not solve this.

When I run `npm test`, this is my output:

```
D:\my-project>npm test --no-cache

> my-project@0.8.0 test D:\my-project
> jest

 FAIL  tests\Foo.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    D:/my-project/tests/Foo.test.js: Unexpected token (8:19)
         6 | describe('A suite', () => {
         7 |   it('should render without throwing an error', () => {
      >  8 |     expect(shallow(<Foo />).contains(<div className='foo'>Bar</div>)).toBe(true);
           |                    ^
         9 |   });
        10 |
        11 |   it('should be selectable by class "foo"', () => {

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.089s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

So Jest is working in some way, because it is running the test, but not the correct way I expected it to.

Simple functions like: 1+2=3 are running through the test successfully.

I appreciate any help from the community.

**Thank you**

Comment: in git `import Foo from './Foo';` this is `import Foo from '../Foo';` did you change it intetionally?

Comment: @Edwin yes I did, it's in the same folder in my project.

Comment: Adjust test env to `"presets": ["es2015", "react"]`, run jest with `--no-cache` flag. If you upgraded jest from previous version, remove all node_modules and install them again, or go with Yarn, as it's more reliable.

Comment: @MichałPierzchała I did what you said already, as one can see in my code. Is there any other configuration I have to take care of in Webpack 2? Do I need a separate jest configfile or anything similiar?